# GroupBy and Count - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my application, i send out surveys and group and count similar and non-similar responses. This is how my group and count is working now

NB: Take this instance as if the survey was answered by 2 clients.

Client 1 and Client 2 both selected `Good` for question 1

**Responses**

```
question                                     Ans

How would you describe my services?          Good (2) 
How would you describe my services?          Good (2) 


Gender                                       Male(1)
Gender                                       Female(1)
```

How can take out the redundancy. the question repeats itself and also, when the answers repeat itself with the count.

**Responses**

```
question                                Name         Ans

How would you describe my services?                Good (2) 


Gender                                             Male(1), Female(1)
```

**Model**

```
public function count_answers() 
  {        
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class)->select('answer', DB::raw('count(*) as counter'))->groupBy('answer');
  }
```

**View**

```
@forelse ($data->questions as $item)
@foreach ($item->answers as $answer)
<tr>     
 <td width="30%">{{ $item->title }}</td>
 <td>
@foreach ($item->count_answers as $answer)
 <div>{{$answer->answer}} ({{$answer->counter}})</div>
@endforeach    
</td> 
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
 public function view_survey_response(Survey $data) 
  {
    $data = Survey::where('id', $data->id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

    return view('answer.response', compact('data'));
  };
```

Comment: What are you passing to the view?

Comment: Post your controller code as well

Comment: @apokryfos I am passing the question and the (answers and its count). so if the two clients selected the same answer, it shows the answer and the count

Comment: I meant the actual code of how you're creating the view variable `$data` and `$item`

Comment: @apokryfos, i am passing the question and the answers

Comment: @SalmanZafar added the controller. check update

Comment: aren't you overriding $data variable 

 public function view_survey_response(Survey $data) 
  {
    $data = Survey::where('id', $data->id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

    return view('answer.response', compact('data'));
  };

change $data to $survey or else and then try

Comment: @SalmanZafar, same results if i change the variable